# Can I have a PHP/Perl script to add some text/code to the end of all PHP files?

Tags: php

I need to rescript every file on my website by putting a footer at the bottom.

Comment: are you creating files on the fly or want to re-script existing ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

This will add the line `$footer_code` to the end of all `php` files in `$dir`.

```
<?php

  $dir = 'YOUR DIRECTORY';
  $footer_code = "footer code";

  if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if (substr($file, -4) == '.php') {
          $fh = fopen($file, 'a') or die("can't open file");
          fwrite($fh, $footer_code);
          fclose($fh);
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
  }

?>
```

Comment: substr($file, -1, 4) returns just "p" you should use substr($file, -4, 4) or just substr($file, -4) to get .php  out of the file name.

Comment: @bhu Correction made. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If this is some boilerplate code that all of your pages need, then might I suggest using some sort of abstract class that all of the actual pages in your website extend.  This way all of the common code can be kept in one file and you don't have to worry about separately updating every single one of your pages every time you have an update for the common code.

```
<?php
    abstract class AbstractPage {
        // Constructor that children can call 
        protected function __construct() {
        }

        // Other functions that may be common
        private function displayHeader() {}
        private function displaySidebar() {}
        private function displayFooter() {}
        abstract protected function displayUniquePageInfo();

        public function display() {
            $this->displayHeader();
            $this->displaySidebar();
            $this->displayUniquePageInfo();
            $this->displayFooter();
        }

    }

    // Next have a page that inherits from AbstractPage
    public class ActualPage extends AbstractPage {
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        // Override function that displays each page's different info
        protected function displayUniquePageInfo() {
            // code
        }
    }

    // Actually display the webpage
    $page = new ActualPage();
    $page->display();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an Apache module lets you set a common footer for every file served, check this for mroe -> http://freshmeat.net/projects/mod_layout/

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind for future scripts. However that wasn't what I wanted in particular

Comment: If thats not what you want you can do some Bash magic to append a string in all files.